# Android: Generate Random Word from List of Words

Tags: android, eclipse, random, textview

My goal is to click a textView and it to display a random word from a list of words. How could i accomplish this? Sorry for newbie question.

Comment: [random number generator in java](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=random+number+generator+in+java&oq=random+numb&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.6023j0j8&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Thank you, but how could i choose randomly from a list of words, not numbers

Comment: `lost_of_words.get(random_no)`.

Answer (score 0):

write only two lines and do a trick.

```
Collections.shuffle(lost_of_words);
        lost_of_words.get(0);
```